# Negative binomial regression in presence of autocorrelation

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, negative-binomial-distribution, robust-standard-error

I am running a negative binomial regression on frequency data. My y variable has very material autocorrelation at lag 1,2.

Am I correct in that the error estimate on any estimated parameter under negative binomial / glm methods is questionable under autocorrelation.  If so is the standard ols test of looking at residual structure sufficient? Or are there ways to correct?

More generally does it make sense when autocorrelation is very material and at multiple lags to run frequency based glm models such as the negative binomial?

Answer (score 2):

You have given few details, so there is not much we can say. What does your response variable represent? How many observations? Time: daily, monthly, hourly, ... obs? ...   You say:  "My y variable has very material autocorrelation at lag 1,2."  but what matters for regression, is not the autocorrelation in $y$ itself, but autocorrelation in the residuals.  Is that also large? Often I have seen that autocorrelation disappears when a good fitting model is found.

Yes, the usual results, especially standard errors, are doubtful with autocorrelated residuals, but maybe you can save the day with some kind of robust standard errors.  To say much more that this we really need some context.